# I want to use order by function using active records in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

There are three Status types in my register table. They are pending,following and completed. So I want to get the count of each Status using active records. This is the code I have written. But I did not get any value pass to the controller.
This the model code

```
<?php
class Manager_Profile_Model extends CI_Model{

    function index(){
        $this->db->select('Status,COUNT(Status) AS count');
        $this->db->order_by('Status');
        $query = $this->db->get('register');
        foreach($query -> result() as $row){
            $data[] = array(
                 'status' =>$row->Status,
                'count' => $row->count

                );
            }
        return $data;
        }
    }

?>
```

And this is the controller

```
<?php
class Manager_Profile_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('Manager_Profile_Model');
        $data = $this->Manager_Profile_Model;

        print_r($data);

   }
}
```

?>

Its really great if someone can help me. Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe `GROUP_BY` as below:

```
function index(){
    $this->db->select('Status,COUNT(Status) AS count');
    $this->db->group_by('Status');
    $query = $this->db->get('register');
    foreach($query -> result() as $row){
        $data[] = array(
             'status' =>$row->Status,
            'count' => $row->count

            );
        }
    return $data;
    }
}
```

AND

```
class Manager_Profile_Controller extends CI_Controller{
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('Manager_Profile_Model');
        $data = $this->Manager_Profile_Model->index();

        print_r($data);

   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but here I did not get all the status types in the database to the controller.Do I need to do any alterations in the model code inorder to get the all the status types and their counts???